# Global string replacement of "/" to "-" in date format string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string which is 26/12/1999. Now i want to convert it to 26-12-1999 but I am getting problems. Using simple '/' by '-' not working. //g is taking itself as comments. Using /g is not fetching desired results. Pls help.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body> 
<script> 
var a = "26/12/1987";
var b = a.replace("/","-");
console.log(b);
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Please Help!

Comment: What do you mean by `/g`??

Comment: @IanS Global flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using /g is not fetching desired results.

It is, you are probably just using it improperly. You should pass the regex, not string.

```
var a = "26/12/1987";
var b = a.replace(/\//g,"-");
console.log(b);
```

Comment: If you're down voting, please comment so as I could know what should I improve / clarify in my answer.

Comment: @Chetan I'm jealous? How?

Comment: I just write answer in detail and made a jsfiddle for that. And you give me down vote.

Comment: @Chetan You did nothing expect providing the link to JSFiddle, remaining part is just the same as in my answer. How was that an answer?

Comment: Yes that's I want to tell you, you have just write logic, I made it same as the question and provide fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114719/discussion-between-chetan-sanghani-and-nicael).

Comment: @Chetan Right. So your "answer" was just an improvement to mine, you should have suggested an edit :)

Comment: @Chetan Have you clicked "move to chat" accidentally by the way?

Comment: @Chetan And wasn't that you jealous because you downvoted my posts?